# GMF runtime notation convert to EditPart

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

How can I receive from org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.notation.impl.ShapeImpl Object the corresponding EditPart? Or how can I receive from ShapeImpl(emf.ecore not runtime) the corresponding EditPart?

Answer (score 4):

I think EditPartViewer's editPart Registery should be able to return you the editpart from the View model (ie shape).

```
EditPart ep = viewer.getEditPartRegistry().get(view);
```

I think that should do it.